# Printing the final queue after performing several operations on it

Tags: c++, queue

I am learning c++ and while executing the following code i am getting the garbage value.I checked the algorithm part and it seems to be correct but if wrong please tell me.I have used the functions like add to add or insert element ,del function to delete,empty function to empty the queue and finally i have function front whose work is to return the front value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Queue {
    private :

        vector<char> data_;

        int front_, rear_;
    public :
    Queue(): front_(-1),rear_(-1) { data_.resize(20); }

        ~Queue() {};

        int empty() {

            if (front_==rear_) {

                front_ = rear_ = -1 ;
                return 1;
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }
        void add(char x) {

            if (front_ == -1)

                front_ = 0 ;
                rear_=rear_+1;
                data_[rear_]=x;

        }
        void del( ) {front_=front_+1;}


        char front() { return front_ ; }

} ; // End of the class
int main( ) {
    Queue q;
    char str[20];

    cin >> str;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)

        q.add(str[i]);

    while (!q.empty()) {

        cout << q.front();

        q.del();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: In addition to stepping through the code, line by line, you can examine the value of your variables, which will be useful, as this sounds like a pointer problem. Btw, if you use Linux, then the DDD debugger might be of use for this particular problem. Just take a look at [this picture](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/all.png) !

Comment: Review Issues:   front() returns char? (instead return int)    "char str[20];"?  (instead use "string str") for loop in main uses int? (instead use uint)

Comment: Another review issue: Use proper indentation and don't add an empty line after your control statements. The formatting around `if (front_ == -1)` is extremely misleading. Also, the problem with `front()` is not that it returns `char`, it's that it doesn't read from `data_`. That will probably get you started.

Comment: @2785528 _for loop in main uses int? (instead use uint)_ I've read long debates whether an array index should be _signed_ or _unsigned_. However, [`strlen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) returns `size_t`. Hence, if `int` is a bad candidate then `uint` (actually `unsigned`) is not much better but `size_t` might be. (I learnt this the hard way when we ported our software from 32 to 64 bit.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff - good response, thanks. I have no problems either way, I was reacting to my compiler's warning about comparing uint to int in that loop.  Because this code is marked C++, I think the var 'str' should be std::string (and a few more related changes).

Comment: @2785528 When I was developing 32 bit only I had the imagination that `unsigned` would've machine word width (i.e. pointer size) and used it extensively. The day we switched to x64, there was a "bad awakening". - I had to fix tons of warnings. However, concerning `std::string`, I fully agree.